# Multiple Open ports on a server, is that safe?

Tags: nmap, ports, network-scanners

Using nmap I try to scan a server as a result I get multiple open ports.
For example when I try to scan `domain.com` as a result:

```
7/tcp open echo
9/tcp open discard
13/tcp open daytime
21/tcp filtered ftp
22/tcp filtered ssh
23/tcp open telnet
25/tcp open smtp
26/tcp open rsftp
37/tcp open time
53/tcp filtered domain
79/tcp open finger
80/tcp open http
81/tcp open hosts2-ns
88/tcp open kerberos-sec
106/tcp open pop3pw
110/tcp open pop3
111/tcp open rpcbind
113/tcp open ident
119/tcp open nntp
135/tcp open msrpc
139/tcp open netbios-ssn
143/tcp open imap
144/tcp open news
179/tcp filtered bgp
199/tcp open smux
389/tcp open ldap
427/tcp open svrloc
443/tcp open https
444/tcp open snpp
445/tcp open microsoft-ds
465/tcp open smtps
513/tcp open login
514/tcp open shell
515/tcp open printer
543/tcp open klogin
544/tcp open kshell
548/tcp open afp
554/tcp open rtsp
587/tcp open submission
631/tcp open ipp
646/tcp open ldp
873/tcp open rsync
990/tcp open ftps
993/tcp open imaps
995/tcp open pop3s
1025/tcp open NFS-or-IIS
1026/tcp open LSA-or-nterm
1027/tcp open IIS
1028/tcp open unknown
1029/tcp open ms-lsa
1110/tcp open nfsd-status
1433/tcp open ms-sql-s
1720/tcp open h323q931
1723/tcp open pptp
1755/tcp open wms
1900/tcp open upnp
2000/tcp open cisco-sccp
2001/tcp open dc
2049/tcp open nfs
2121/tcp open ccproxy-ftp
2717/tcp open pn-requester
3000/tcp filtered ppp
```

and much more other open ports.

I want to know if these open ports have dangerous impact?

It's possible to exploit these services behind open ports?

Comment: This question is way too broad, you're asking can 62 ports be exploited, the answer is - yes. Please edit this question, as it stands this will only be removed.

Comment: Just these ports are some examples .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a lot of misunderstandings and assumptions in your question, but I will try to address them.

First, you are scanning a domain (I assume from the Internet). Just because nmap shows them as `open` does not mean that they actually are. There are a lot of devices in between you and the domain that could be responding to the scan, and they might just be responding to anything you send them without actually having the service running.

Second, just having a service running is not bad. Having more services running than you need just opens you up to a greater range of threats for no reason, so the advice is to only expose the services you absolutely need.

Third, "is it possible to exploit these services behind open ports" is the wrong question. It's like asking if a door you are looking at across the street is unlocked or not. There is no way to tell just by knowing that there is a door. You need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Not surely:

- It may be possible that actually there is a complex network of physical or virtual machines behind a gateway, with correctly separated privileges and protected from each other.
- It is also possible that actually you've found some "trap system", which has many open ports, but instead of giving real, attackable services, in fact it logs your activities. Probably only a small part of the open ports (and not surely 80 and 443) belong to real services.
- You may have found only a single service which uses many ports.

Typically, having so many open ports is a weak defense, particularly if there is no focus for privilege separation for the services behind them. But don't think that it is always bad.